# How to change "%" to "Point" in "ng-circle-progress" in angular-7?

Tags: css, angular

I have just started a angular based web application where has a circle progress bar and I used `"ng-circle-progress"` for this section. I need to change `"%"` unit to `"point"` as per the design, but can't find any options throughout the plugin to implement this. Please check the link and code given below and find a solution for this.

Link of "ng-circle-progress" - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-circle-progress

**Code -----**

```
<circle-progress 
  [percent]="60" 
  [titleFontSize]="40" 
  [showSubtitle]="false" 
  [showUnits]="false" 
  [outerStrokeColor]="'#707070'" 
  [innerStrokeColor]="'#D4D4D4'" 
  [radius]="100" 
  [backgroundPadding]="7" 
  [outerStrokeWidth]="5" 
  [space]="-5" 
  [innerStrokeWidth]="5" 
  [animation]="true" 
  [animationDuration]="1000">
</circle-progress>
```

Answer (score 3):

As I can see in the documentation, by Keeping `[showSubtitle]="false" [showUnits]="false"`

and by adding other option `subtitleFormat` with callback function you can achieve your requirement.

for  `subtitleFormat` callback implementation you can refere [here](https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress/issues/56)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ng-circle-progress` has a property named `units` which defaults to '%'.

You can change it directly.

```
<circle-progress 
  [units]="point"
  [showUnits]="true" 
  ...
  ...
  >
</circle-progress>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to specify `units: "A"` in my options in my ts file

and include in `[showUnits]="true"` in my html.